# Blockly.Xml.textToDom expected an <xml> document

Tags: javascript, xml, blockly, google-blockly

**I have been trying to restore all my used blocks from localStorage.I am looping through all the local saved blocks but I got the following error. It would be great if I can get some help.**

**Error:**

```
blockly_compressed.js:1274 Uncaught Error: Blockly.Xml.textToDom expected an 
<xml> document.
at Object.Blockly.Xml.textToDom (blockly_compressed.js:1274)
at restoreWorkspace ((index):312)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):115)
Blockly.Xml.textToDom   @   blockly_compressed.js:1274
restoreWorkspace    @   (index):312
onclick @   (index):115
```

**Code to restore all the blocks:**

```
 // restore blocks
    function restoreWorkspace() {
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
            let program=(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
            Blockly.mainWorkspace.clear();
            let textToDom = Blockly.Xml.textToDom(program);
            Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace(Blockly.mainWorkspace, textToDom);
        }
    }
```

**Code to save compositions:**

```
   function saveWorkspace() {
        let xml = Blockly.Xml.workspaceToDom(Blockly.mainWorkspace);
        let domToPretty = Blockly.Xml.domToPrettyText(xml);
        var ranInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        window.localStorage.setItem("myProgram"+ranInt, domToPretty);
    }
```

Comment: Hrm, I don't see anything immediately odd about your code... if you log out domToPretty in saveWorkspace + log out the value of program in restoreWorkspace, what values do you get?

Comment: Sorry , can you please eloborate your opinion again?

Comment: Please log out the value of the domToPretty variable and log out the value of the program variable, and update your question with the values. (P.S. you may have a bit more luck getting help in the Blockly Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/blockly )

Comment: Thanks for the help. I already tried somethings with google blockly groups. Though no lucks but I am trying to find a way out.

Comment: @AmberB. I have tried all the sources and finally i have decided to just keep my code as it is and let other have some thoughts.

Comment: console logging the `domToPretty` variable would help in troubleshooting the issue

Comment: I have already resolved this issue. Though thanks @NithinKumarBiliya

Comment: @SakhawatHossain just because you've resolved it doesn't mean it can't help future visitors. Consider writing a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to provide a resource for future visitors with the same problem as you.